# How to use Kotlin Coroutine.LiveData + Retrofit for API call while showing a progress bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-livedata, coroutine

I am trying to do an API call using coroutine and retrofit with the MVVM architecture. I would like to show a progress bar while waiting for the API response to be ready (with a timeout of 3 seconds).

In the **View Model** I am using Coroutine.LiveData

```
class BootstrapViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val repository : ConfigRepository =
    ConfigRepository()

val configurations = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val retrievedConfigs = repository.getConfigurations(4)

    emit(retrievedConfigs)
}
```

}

What I have so far in the activity is just a simulation of API call to update progress bar:

```
launch {
        // simulate API call
        val configFetch = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (progressState.value != 100) {
                progressState.postValue(progressState.value?.plus(1))
                delay(50)
            }
        }

        // suspend until fetch is finished or return null in 3 sec
        val result = withTimeoutOrNull(3000) { configFetch.await() }

        if (result != null) {
            // todo: process config... next steps
        } else {
            // cancel configFetch
            configFetch.cancel()

            // show error

        }
    }
```

I can also observe the livedata as below and works fine:

```
bootstrapViewModel.configurations.observe(this, Observer {
        //response is ready
    })
```

Everything works fine separated. However, when I try to use the livedata inside coroutine scope things get messy. Is there anyway to *await()* for a coroutine livedata (like how I did for *configFetch*)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
val _progressBarVisibility = MutableLiveData<Int>() // Use this with postValue
val progressBarVisibility: LiveData<Int> = _progressBarVisibility

val configurations = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _progressBarVisibility.postValue(View.VISIBLE)    

    // you can just stimulate API call with a delay() method
    delay(3000)    //3 seconds

    val retrievedConfigs = repository.getConfigurations(4)

    _progressBarVisibility.postValue(View.GONE)
    emit(retrievedConfigs)
}
```

After that in your Activity:

```
viewModel.progressBarVisibility.observe(this, Observer{
  pbVisibilityView.visibity = it
}
```

If  you are asking about retrofit in particular, this is how you can do it.

In your `DataApi` interface, you just mark the method as `suspend`ed:

```
interface DataApi{
  @GET("endpointHere")
  suspend fun getData() : Result<Data>
}
```

The rest is just as I described above. Just replace `getConfigurations(4)` with `getData()`